# How to access internet on one VM which doesn't have internet access via another VM which have the internet access?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

what setting should i have to make in order to have such arrangement.
I want to access internet on one VM via another VM. 
What steps i need to follow to get this done ?

Comment: Hi Hammad and welcome to Superuser! Can you please add to your answer what you've tried already? This also includes things like I searched the internet for "two Virtual Machines one network", tried [this solution](https://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-virtualbox-to-emulate-a-network/) but it didn't work because [reasons].
Also, please include a bit more detail on what your setup is.

Comment: Yes, please follow Saaru's suggestions. Specifically, as a network admin, when I'm answering your question, I would recommend including the following:

1.) operating system (having a Win Server VM makes everything a LOT easier)
2.) IP addresses + subnet masks (I need to know whether they're on different subnets)
3.) your hypervisor
4.) details about why one VM can't have internet access

Comment: You haven't given enough info for anyone without clear knowledge of your network topology to do any reasonable "guesswork-troubleshooting".

Comment: I have given this scenario to implement it. Task is to access via other VM I have tried it on different networks, like NAT, NAT Network, Bridged Network, Host-only. One has the internet access while other didn't. How to achieve this task?  subnet is same of both the VMs

Comment: Oh. Well, even if they're on the same subnet, my answer of using RRAS on a server VM should still work or even VPN encapsulation. Some details might just be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As Saaru pointed out in their comment, I don't have information on your setup. I will be assuming your setup in this answer. If I'm incorrect, please do feel free to correct me and I will confer with you further about your issue.

I'm going to assume that since you say that one VM has internet access and the other doesn't, that they're on two different logical subnets.

Let's say that VM 1 has the IP address of 192.168.1.1/24 and VM 2 has the IP address of 10.0.0.1/24. Let's also say that VM 1 has internet access and VM 2 doesn't.

There's multiple ways we could approach this. If you must have the second VM get its internet connection from the first, we can have VM 1 run some version of Windows Server. From there, we can have VM 1 set up with a second NIC on the same subnet as VM 2 (i.e. 10.0.0.2/24) and set VM 1 up with the Routing and Remote Access Services (RRAS) server role and set up the NAT protocol to route data from VM 2 through VM 1 out of its external interface.

Additionally, if VM 1 is running Windows 10 and you cannot get it onto a server OS, you can get Windows Server on a 3rd VM and then go through the above instructions to set up RRAS on that using the above instructions, only this time, set up peer-to-peer links (/30s) from each VM to the RRAS VM using secondary NICs on each of the VMs. Then connect the RRAS system to the internet.

If you can't/don't want to set up an RRAS system, you can try setting up a VPN connection from the second VM to the first VM, utilizing a secondary NIC connection.

The theme is that for any system on a separate subnet to reach a system on another, it has to go through a router that will route packets through one NIC and out another to another network (in this case, the internet).

I will update as you add details.